# Question regarding nested quantifier, what's the difference between --> and ∧

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

Say the domain is all students in X university
K(x, y): x knows y
H(x): x is a history student

For question: some student knows all history students
the answer is: ∃x∀y(H(y) --> K(x, y))

I kinda get the gist of the answer, but what is wrong with this expression?
∃x∀y(H(y) ∧ K(x, y))

For the correct answer, it is read as 'There exists some x such that for every y, if y is a history student, then x knows y.'

For the flawed expression, it is read as 'There exists some x such that for every y, y is a history student and x knows y'

My problem is, is the flawed expression wrong because it claims all students in X university are history students? Or it's due to some other reason? My understanding is only when the university only has history major will the second expression be correct, am I understanding this right?

Any assistance would be appreciated! I'm so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you use an $\land$, then every student at the university $X$ ends up becoming a history student.

Remember that the quantifiers range over the whole domain, which in this case is all students at university $X$. However, this claim is not interested in the students who are not history students. So, to restrict yourself to those, you say '*If* you are a history student, then this one particular student will know you'. Which is why you want to use the $\to$

Comment: Thank you so much, so logically speaking the second one could be correct if university X only has a history major, in that case, all students in the university are automatically becoming history students, and knowing all history students thus becomes knowing all students in the university, is this right?

Comment: @SilZec It would be true, yes, but it would still not be the correct translation of the original sentence.